# How to add extra details on new order placed template Magento

Tags: email, magento

I want to add some extra details to order placed email.I found the html file inside the locale but i want to add dynamic text.For that i want to add that code from there where it call this file to send email.Can someone help that where can i find the file where order email is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override this model 
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php 
rewrite this method

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
  {
  --- default code ----
  $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'dynamicvariable'    => $dynamicvariable,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
  --- default code ----
 }
```

in above method I have added dynamic variable you can use in order email templete system -> transactional emails -> new order template
like this

```
{{var $dynamicvariable}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Create a file On this location app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/email/shipnote.phtml in this file add your code like :-

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$note = $order->getYourData(); // (or whatever is the code for getting the your data message)
echo $note;
```

Step 2 :- 
Now open your transactional email template you can find it system->>Transactional Emails or app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html and add following code in it:-

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/shipnote.phtml' order=$order}}
```